# mpirun problem: HYDU_create_process (permission denied)

Tags: linux, mpi

I'm trying to build an executable file, on the manual it gives two options to build the file, with `make` and `cmake`. (Note that the program runs on linux)

So I followed the procedure and everything seems to work up to the point when I try to run a benchmark example provided with the code, by `mpirun`:

```
└─$ mpirun -np 1 $HOME/sparta/bench spa_mac \< in.free

\[proxy:0:0@kalig\] HYDU_create_process (utils/launch/launch.c:73): execvp error on file /home/gioggior/sparta/bench (Permission denied)
```

`

I tried to build the file both with `Cmake` and `make` but the error is always the same after I try to run the example by `mpirun`.

I have already installed `MPICH2` (I've already seen that the program has problems with `OpenMPI`)

I thought it was a permission problem but I've already checked that the file has already permissions `w-x-r`.

I tried to search for a solution with no avail, however this is my first approach to Linux so I'm very unexperienced.

The open source code I'm trying to run is called SPARTA DSMC if it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man mpirun`, you are trying to execute a directory...

I think the command you want is (if sparta compiled program is in `.../bench` directory

```sh
cd $HOME/sparta/bench
mpirun -np 1 ./spa_mac < in.free
```

But did you try to run it directly?

```sh
cd $HOME/sparta/bench
./spa_mac < in.free
```

Comment: It works by specyfing the path before ./spa_mac < in.free. Running it directly returns command not found. Thank you,it was simple but very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands by order

1. mpicc -O $HOME/sparta/bench spa_mac -o in.free
2. mpirun -np 1 ./in.free

-O flag optimizes the file same as C compiler